# How to get high folder uri in html on android web server

Tags: android, html, web, uri, href

I'm developing an app that installs files ( index.html, style.css ... ) to SD-card of phone for web server

The web server needs to get mp3 files to play.

My problem is what I couldn't find where is my mp3 file??

For example..

It works fine If i put mp3 file in same folder of index.html.

```
<a href="somthing.mp3"  
     data-format="mp3 ogg">mp3 file</a>
```

However, I couldn't get the route of mp3 if I put higher folder than the folder of index.html..
I tried

```
<a href="/sdcard/MUSIC/somthing.mp3"
  data-format="mp3 ogg">mp3 file</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/sdcard/MUSIC/somthing.mp3"
  data-format="mp3 ogg">mp3 file</a>
```

"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.html" is my android web server ...

How can I get my file???

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to access the SD card?

Comment: I have permissions : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>          
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

Comment: JellyBean upwards introduces the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Are you on 4.1+?

Comment: Also, you should be using Environment.getExternalStoreDirectory() for the root of the sdcard as it varies with device.

Comment: My app supports targetSdkVersion="15" (ICS) and it's not working even I added the permission.

Comment: I tried <a href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/mnt/sdcard/MUSIC/somthing.mp3"
  data-format="mp3 ogg">mp3 file</a> it's not working.

Comment: and <a href="/mnt/sdcard/MUSIC/somthing.mp3" data-format="mp3 ogg">mp3 file</a> also not working

Comment: hmm.. Should it be edited in different file?